# PHPStorm and module references

Tags: php, module, directory-structure, phpstorm, project-structure

I have the following files at my PHP project:

```
index.php
private/module1.php
private/module2.php
```

The `index.php` references `module1.php` this way:

```
require_once('private/module1.php');
```

By its turn, `module1.php` requires `module2.php`, so it has the following line:

```
require_once('private/module2.php');
```

I need to inform the relative path from root for it to work. I guess that's because **require_once** command expects a path from the *current* document, which happens to be index.php. The problem is that PHP Storm can't manage this reference. For instance, it doesn't turn the string `private/module2.php` into an hyperlink, nor spot it as an actual reference.

How to solve this?

Comment: Personally, I always specify the paths relative to the current file, i.e. `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/module2.php';` . It might sound backwards, changing your code to fit an IDE, but I consider it good practice to have unambiguous file references.

Comment: Yeah, but I value IDE automation. If I get no answer, I'll probably fallback to something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to configure your PhpStorm project correctly by specifying the include paths PhpStorm should use to resolve references.

Go to File -> Settings -> PHP.

There you should add the project root directory (the one where your index.php resides) to the list of include paths.

When this is done PhpStorm should resolve the path in `require_once('private/module2.php')`.

Additionally you could add the *private* directory to the list of include paths PHP uses via [set_include_path()](http://php.net/set_include_path) somewhere in you *index.php*. Then you could just call `require_once('module2.php')` from your *module1.php*.

Again, you would have to add the *private* directory to the list of include paths PhpStorm uses to enable it resolve this reference.

Comment: Does this configure this path for all projects, or just the current project?  I need to configure it for the current project only.

Comment: @EricG Yes. And to be sure it is, you should see "For current project" at the top of the settings window.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the base url.
Like

```
require_once($base_url . 'private/module2.php');
```

The base url can be defined somewhere by yourself or you could use the $_SERVER variable to get it
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm can't make the reference because it's looking for

```
index.php
private/module1.php
private/private/module2.php
```

`module1.php` should just require the filename `module2.php`:

`require_once('module2.php);`

Comment: Thanks, but there's nothing new in your answer. Changing to simply `'module.php'` breaks the website, causing the message `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Haven't you noticed the text " need to inform the relative path from root for it to work" in my question?